# Exporting mail box from windows live mail to outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-live-mail

I tried to export my current mails form windows live mail to outlook 2010. When i did that export option with Microsoft exchange what its doing actually exporting it to outlook data file which shows up in outlook. rather than to my email account. The funny thing is i can export it to outlook even without a email account.

The problem that now am facing is. Even after import of all my emails which like 3GB Outlook actually fetch those mails again from my gmail account.

I dont want to export the mails from live mail to outlook in a outlook file. Rather i want it in the mailbox folders.. The outlook data file take very long time to display my mails.  Is there any tweak to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IMAP in Outlook, you can specify how much data it should keep downloaded and it synchronizes all your folders easily, without any import/export hassle.

So in Gmail you need to enable IMAP in the settings, then set up a new account in Outlook to use IMAP. I think somewhere along the line you select what folders you want and how long to keep them.

Using IMAP synchronizes your emails, so if you delete something in Outlook it will delete in Gmail.

But for the purpose of importing, you can say download everything and stop synchronizing.

Comment: yeah.. i know about imap.. that's what am actually using for windows live mail right now..

Comment: So you just want to download it all and use in outlook? Not sure what you mean exactly..